# Different Ship To and Billing address on Guest check-out?

Tags: shipping-address, billing-address

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
all extensions from Amasty
```

We are switching from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.2-p1. We do local gifts delivery and I just noticed that during the Guest check-out, **there is only one address = SHIP TO** (which we renamed to 'Delivery address'). The problem with this is that *most all of our customers will be sending a present to someone else so the Delivery (Ship to) and Billing address will be different* (they will be paying for a gift for someone else which will go to the person's who is getting the gift address).

**How best to change this?**

---

UPDATED on September 10th, 2021:

Natha Odedara is right - there is an option in **Review & Payments --> PAYMENT METHOD** -> When I click on  'Cash on Delivery' which has a check mark in "**My billing and shipping address are the same**" which makes sense.

***Will the same come up once we have the Paypal option which lets customers just fill in their credit card details on our website and process it from there?***

Comment: There should be an option such as My billing and shipping address are different which will allow you to enter a different address for shipping and billing.

Comment: @Natha Odedara You are right - there is an option in Review & Payments --> PAYMENT METHOD -> When I click on  'Cash on Delivery' which has a check mark in "My billing and shipping address are the same" which makes sense. Will the same come up once we have the Paypal option which lets customers just fill in their credit card details on our website and process it from there?

Comment: Yes ... The Standard Checkout flow - i.e. unless someone has customized it to behave differently - gives you the option to choose the same v/s different Bill_To/Ship_To by checking v/s unchecking the "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox seen in the Checkout Process.